# Tabbarcontroller in objective C

Tags: ios

I have an application which uses tabbarcontroller. It has two tabs- tab A and tab B. The tabs are mapped to view controllers through navigationcontroller. The mapping goes like this. Tab A-> Navigation controllerA->tableViewControllerA. Tab B->Navigation ControllerB->tableViewControllerB. TableViewControllerA-> links to-> tableviewcontroller B. tableviewcontroller B->links to -> Detail screen.
The problem is when I click the tab A it takes me to relevant view. Then I click tab B and it takes me to correct view and then to its detail. But when I click the tab A again the view loaded remains there. I have to click tab A again to load the tableviewcontrollerA.

Comment: This is unexpected behavior. Can you please explain how the TableViewControllerA links to TableViewControllerB? Or post some code?

Comment: this is the expected behaviour for a `UITabBarController`, the point is that the user _finds_ the tab in _the same state where he leave it_. If you want to go to the first controller take a look to the `popToRootViewController` method

Comment: It sounds like you're describing the expected behavior of the UITabBarController.  If you are looking for some other behavior, as a start, you need to clarify what behavior you're trying to implement.

Comment: Thanks a lot. popToRootViewController worked.